# Keeping the results with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, join

I connect four tables, but if I do a GROUP BY with a propertie of the fourth table, I get different results. This is the Query:

Comment: Can you also post the expected result. The query and the result it generates look correct. The first line from the first output has been divided into two line based on two values of `SKU.[Reorder Cycle]` - NULL and 2M

Comment: Can you also add column headers

Comment: you could just get the max(sku.[record cycle]) unless you can have more than one, in which case figure out what sort of rules you want to get the one you want and use that logic in the max()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, this was doing the job(oke, I made a pivot of it):

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options:

1. JOIN back to original table using nested query.

   ```
   SELECT TA.col1, AggrFunc(col2) AS col2, 
       (SELECT col3 -- TOP 1? MAX? It must be single row
        FROM table1 AS TB
        JOIN TA ON TA. = TB. -- INNER JOIN? LEFT OUTER JOIN?
   FROM table1 AS TB JOIN table2 JOIN table3
   GROUP BY TA.col1;
   ```

   Or use a CTE. You have more control on how many rows of extra columns to return

   ```
   WITH CTE AS
   (
       SELECT col1, AggrFunc(col2) AS col2
       FROM ... JOINs
       GROUP BY col1
   )
   SELECT CTE.*, table1.col3
   FROM CTE
   JOIN table1 --INNER JOIN? LEFT OUTER JOIN?
   ```
2. Use window function if possible

   ```
   SELECT col1, AggrFunc(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) AS col2, extra_col3
   FROM ...JOINs...
   ```

   then you can put above query a CTE or FROM clause to further filtering or grouping.

   ```
   SELECT
   FROM (query above)
   WHERE ...
   GROUP BY ...
   ```

The question is same: **How do you get single extra_col3(`SKU.[Reorder Cycle]` in your case) row?** How do you pick up one record when there are multiple matches to your grouped data.

Comment: @SavantCode, just a suggestion: could you remove unnecessary code? like code commented out, or columns unrelated.

Comment: Somebody some advise? So I only want to return extra column